# how to convert the json array name with its immediate fieldname using typescript

Tags: node.js, json, typescript

Assume, I have a Json as below:

```
"singleField" : [
{
"fieldName": "company",
"fieldValue": "xyz"
}
]
```

I have to convert this into:

```
"company": [
{
fieldValue": "xyz"
}
]
```

Kindly guide me to do this using typescript code.